Tamari lattice and bicategory coherence
Reference links:
Tamari lattice (Wikipedia): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamari_lattice
Associahedra: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamari_lattice#/media/File:Tamari_lattice.svg
The Tamari lattice  is the combinatorial scheme  of the associativity law on (fixed) $n$ elements, its Hasse digram  is (the  1-dimensional skeleton of) the associahedra, is immediate regognize a categorification of it, just think to a bicategory (with strict unities, with objets $o_0, o_1,\ldots$ with non identity morphisms  just: $\ n: o_{n-1}\to o_n,\ n\in \mathbb{N}^+$). Then  each (oriented) edge is inducted by  a  one associativity canonical (iso)morphism as: $\ldots a_{X, Y, Z}\ldots\ :\ \ldots ((X\cdot Y)\cdot Z)\ldots\ \to\ \ldots (X\cdot (Y\cdot Z))\ldots$ in a unique way.
In the wiki link  there is a pic of the associahedra of order  $4$, is easy (thinking it categorized) recognize that it is commutative (pentagons by the usual bicategory diagran axiom, rectangles by naturality), by the bicategory coherence  this is true in general.
I ask if this is there is a direct (combinatorial, diagrammatic) proof of commutativity of categorified (1-dimensional skeleton) of the $n$-associahedra.
If so, this is another way to prove coherence in a bicategory (coherence about unitary morphisms is easy), and get a pretty result of coherence about lax-bicategory (where $a_{X, Y, Z}$ arent' necessarily isomorphisms).
